# Input tipo Date com ano contendo 6 dígitos

Tags: html, html5, input, data

Reparem no *snippet* logo abaixo, que o `input` do tipo **`date`** ao ser digitado no valor **ano**, é possível inserir **4**, **5** ou **6** dígitos para ser exato:

```html
<input type="date">
```

Minhas dúvidas são exatamente:

- Para qual finalidade o ano pode ter mais de 4 dígitos?
- Se existir alguma finalidade para isto, como poderia ser aplicado?

> Sei que ao ser utilizado os atributos **`min`** e **`max`**, automaticamente o ano só pode receber **4** dígitos, então por que o valor padrão do ano pode receber até **6**?

Comment: Só passa na minha mente escalabillidade temporal.

Comment: Particularmente, eu acho o input tipo "date" mt ruim. Eu usaria 3 campos separados tipo "number", um para cada informação: dia, mês e ano. Ou um select para cada um.

Comment: depende da aplicação que está a desenvolver. na grande maioria dos casos não fa sentido ter mais do que 4 digitos, mas vai que alguem desenvolve uma plataforma/game que tem como tema os anos futuros. rebuscado mas sei lá

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pra mim é só um padrão um ruim. Claro que um ano pode ter valores de 5 ou 6 dígitos para alguns cenários (não exatamente dentro do [padrão (*standard*) universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), mas ninguém trabalha com isso, o padrão do navegador deveria ser o que mais as pessoas usam e no momento é 4 dígitos (já foi 2 e poderia voltar ser) e o padrão ISO 8601 diz claramente que deve ser 4 (dando a liberdade de ser mais, o que pra mim é uma liberdade ruim porque não tem um padrão fixo, mas ele adota um número que faz mais sentido).

Mas note que limitar o mínimo e máximo que pode ser entrado nada muda no Firefox, até mesmo se inicializar com um valor fora. Claro, ao final da digitação ele será considerado inválido, mas trabalha com 6 dígitos. Tente nele:

```html
<input type="date" value="111111-08-09" min="2019-01-01" max="2019-12-31">
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/ValidDate.html).

Solução pra isso no FF? Pode ser que exista algo simples (não achei, tá cheio de respostas erradas por aí), mas acho que a solução atual é fazer o seu próprio que funcione direito.

De fato [foi considerado um *bug* no Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583801) e por isso mudaram, mas consideraram que não poderiam mudar mais radicalmente porque a especificação não manda fazer isto e se fizerem e um dia a especificação mandar fazer outra coisa eles terão algo incompatível. Vamos aguardar o FF arrumar isso (quer abrir um *issue*?). Não sei do Safari.

E a especificação talvez não mude porque pode criar uma incompatibilidade em algum navegador que fez algo a mais, criando um *deadlock* :). Web é uma das piores invenções da computação justamente por essas coisas, a ideia é boa, a implementação é péssima. Estão preocupados com acessibilidade quando nem o básico funciona direito.

Comment: Realmente Maniero, não havia ainda testado no Firefox, mesmo com **min** e **max** o valor ainda pode receber 6 dígitos, será que é seguro utilizar estes tipos de campos, digo em uma aplicação com data de vencimento por exemplo, será que o cara não consegue fazer alguma coisa maliciosamente pelo navegador?

Comment: Maliciosa não porque afinal você valida o dado no servidor sempre, certo? Mas é uma UX ruim.

Comment: Parece problema de implementação mesmo, primeiro pensei que pudesse ser algo ligado ao formato da data, mas parece que não...