# Por que usar um Select Multiple ou um Checkbox?

Tags: html, html5, formulário, ux

Para recuperar múltiplos valores selecionados pelo usuário e gravar em um banco de dados, qual seria a melhor opção de uso? Quais as diferenças entre uma forma e outra?

Comment: Não tem diferença na hora de recuperar porque ele te passo um `array` de informações. Se pode escolher qualquer uma das duas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta é uma escolha que deve fazer de acordo com parâmetros de eXperiência de Usuário (UX). O que faz mais sentido para seu usuário nesta situação? O que vai no banco de dados não deveria ter importância na decisão, pelo menos não de forma prioritária.

O componente de interação com usuário de seleção tem o propósito de ter múltiplas escolhas dentro de um *roll* de itens estabelecidos e que tem alguma relação entre eles, então geralmente você tem uma lista. Você escolhe quais dos itens selecionou.

O componente de interação com usuário de marcação não é uma lista é um item específico, claro você pode ter vários, mas ele é individual. Você diz se quer ativar um item ou não.

Qual das duas situações você tem? Procure fazer a escolha de acordo com a semântica do seu problema.

A interação deve ser a prioridade, mas pense também visualmente o que fica melhor. O seletor pode ficar mais compacto e pode conter mais itens do que é mostrado  (se tiver muitos itens só pode escolher o *select*), tem de forma clara que é um agrupamento de coisas. Isto é bom para seu caso? Algumas pessoas consideram que a acessibilidade é maior com o *checkbox*, não sei se é verdade.

Mas será que seu usuário entende bem o seletor? Em geral este componente tem uma carga cognitiva maior, é preciso analisar isto, se o usuário é menos técnico pode pesar na decisão. Seu usuário usa mais desktop ou mobile? Em qual navegador? E o componente de seleção funciona bem em cada cenário destes? Hoje mesmo [respondi uma pergunta que um componente não funciona bem em todos navegadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402629/101).